# Calculating power of a number

Tags: c++, c

```
  total=a;
  for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
     total=pow(a,b);
```

Problem:
While doing power of 5^2 or any multiple of 5 it is giving output actual   value -1
  otherwise for other number its output is right.

Comment: Why don't you use `i` inside the loop? Maybe you can do without said loop?

Comment: Your loop is just assigning the same thing `b` times.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: without the loop condition the problem is same

Comment: You haven't shown where `a` and `b` come from, and you haven't shown where your "actual output value" is coming from, and you haven't given the minimal compilable example that demonstrates the fault.

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: Iteration using multiplication or the `pow` function. Pick *one*.

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through your code and understand what you told the program to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually calculate the power of a number using a loop, you could do

```
long power(long base, long exp)
{
    long total = 1;
    for(long i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
    {
        total *= base;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Example

```
int main()
{
    long base = 5;
    long exp = 3;
    long answer = power(base, exp);
    std::cout << answer << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
125
```

[Working example](http://cpp.sh/5d5r)

Note this only works with positive, integer exponents.

Comment: The output for 5^2 is still having the same problem

Comment: @VishnuSingh, [No it isn't.](http://cpp.sh/5ujl)

Comment: How is this program even loosely equivalent to what the OP showed?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was taking a stab at what the OP was trying to do. Their current code is *far* from working, so I tried to use my psychic powers to write what they were intending. And if they were allowed to simply use the `std::pow` function, they'd be done, so I went with the multiplicative approach.

Comment: @Cyber: As far as I can tell, he _is_ using the `std::pow` function (and misinterpreting the result). If he's written his own, then we can't see it so we can't do anything but close the question! :)